# Lost internet access after installing Find My iPhone

Tags: find-my-iphone

I installed Find My iPhone and was unable to connect to the internet. I deleted the application and that fixed the issue. However, through iCloud it also installed on my iPad. I cannot delete it from there because there is no icon. When I go into setting and try to turn it off it won't let me because it cannot access the internet. How can I remove it from my iPad?

Answer (score 1):

Did you actually purchase "Find my iPhone"? If you did you can delete the purchase.

You must have a computer around you with iTunes. Sign into your account then, Right click on the App in iTunes, select delete.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have my ipad connected to my computer but there are no apps listed in itunes. I did a sync but I still dont see any of my apps

Comment: Ok, I got it to work. I can see my apps in iTunes. But that one is not listed. I think because I already deleted it from my iPhone. The problem is that I have lost that ability to access the internet on the iPad so I can't turn Find My iPad off.